# Ayuda con funciones anidadas Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Tengo una pagina que carga un Javascript y  contiene esto:

```
(function(f) {
    function qb(a) {
        var b = g.sockets[a];
        b.onopen = b.onclose = b.onmessage = b.onerror = function() {};
        for (var d = 0; d < b.events.length; ++d) U(b.events[d][1]);
        b.events = null;
        try {
            b.close()
        } catch (t) {}
        g.sockets[a] = null
    }

    function tb(a) {
        eval.call(null, a)
    }

})
```

Quisiera saber como llamo a la función tb  desde la consola de chrome porque  me sale el siguiente error VM3784:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: tb is not defined(…)

Answer (score 3):

Buenas, no puedes, debido a que está dentro de una función [anónima](https://geekytheory.com/javascript-funciones-anonimas-y-objetos/), sólo puedes ver el debug (F12 en navegador para sacar la consola) y poner un breakpoint dentro.

Tienes una función anidada dentro de otra, estas funciones suelen llevar el nombre de inner-private, son inner porque son internas y private porque sólo son accesibles desde el código de la función.

Te dejo una página para que lo entiendas mejor.

http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/funciones-en-javascript-variables-objetos-y-anonimas-c111051l/

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[js](/questions/tagged/js)

Answer (score 3):

Como dijo @sakulino, sin modificar el codigo, no es posible a menos que hagas algun eval() hack con el script.
Si lo puedes modificar, lo ideal sera que expongas las funciones internas:

```
var f = (function(f) {
    function qb(a) {
        var b = g.sockets[a];
        b.onopen = b.onclose = b.onmessage = b.onerror = function() {};
        for (var d = 0; d < b.events.length; ++d) U(b.events[d][1]);
        b.events = null;
        try {
            b.close()
        } catch (t) {}
        g.sockets[a] = null
    }

    function tb(a) {
        eval.call(null, a)
    }
    return {
        qb: qb,
        tb: tb
    }
})();

f.gb();
f.tb();
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que trabajes en la menor medida posible con funciones anónimas. Es verdad que brindan mucha comodidad a la hora de trabajar, pero se pueden convertir en un problema. Es un poco mas "dócil" si se tienen en un objeto, el cual puedes tratarlo con más flexibilidad. En el caso de tu código, simplemente no hace falta hacer uso de funciones anidadas. Por ejemplo:

```
function qb(a) {
    var b = g.sockets[a];
    b.onopen = b.onclose = b.onmessage = b.onerror = function() {};
    for (var d = 0; d < b.events.length; ++d) U(b.events[d][1]);
    b.events = null;
    try {
        b.close()
    } catch (t) {}
    g.sockets[a] = null
}

function tb(a) {
    eval.call(null, a)
}
```

Creo que no sería necesario declarar funciones dentro de funciones, si no van a trabajar directamente con los datos internos de la función más externa.